# Как в assembler сравнить значения в регистре с байтом 00h?

Tags: ассемблер

Мне нужно сравнить значения в регистре с байтом 00h

```
getS proc near
mov ebx, 0
mov eax, 0
mov ecx, 0
getSStart:
cmp dword ptr[ebx], 0
jz getSEnd
add ebx, 1
add ecx, 1
jmp getSStart
getSEnd:
mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
ret
getS endp
```

но при запуске программы (программа запускается в консоли) консоль сразу же закрывается. Методом тыка я определил, что проблема в строчке:
cmp dword ptr[ebx], 0. Что мне делать?

Comment: `cmp DWORD PTR [ebx], 0`? Смотря в какую переменную, регистр, и тип данных.

Comment: @Qzim25, а переменная где находится? На стеке? В сегменте `.bss`?

Comment: Ой, не в ту память вы лезете... Это ж практически разыменование NULL. Кстати, а где у вас сравнение *значения в регистре*? его что-то у вас не видно. И, кстати, размер регистра, если это не `bh` какой-нибудь, больше одного байта. Так что надо еще определить, что вы понимаете под сравнением значения регистра с байтом...